# How to contentiously loop through in order to get printer Status

Tags: c#

I have coded a simple console application that checks the status of a printer. When status of a printer changes to a "printing status" the console app simply writes out a message saying "The Printer is now Printing".

Now what i'm having difficulties with is making this program  keep checking the status of printer .. I'm not so sure what loop i have to use and how i can apply it. Please see below for more information:

```
 public static void getPrintJob()
        {
            string printerName = "Some Printer Name";
            string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);
            ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
            {
               if (Convert.ToInt32(printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Value) == 4)
               {
                   Console.Write("Printer is Printing");
               }
```

What kind of loop could i put above for this program to continuously  keep on checking the the printer status? and whenever the status changes to 4 (printing status on the printer i'm targeting ).

Comment: if you want it to run forever, just wrap your foreach block in a while(true) loop.

Comment: @Jay ...with a call to `Thread.Sleep(1000)` or similar, to ensure your process doesn't consume an entire CPU ;-)

Comment: or you can use a timer, and check this every, for example, 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want this to run forever, a while loop will work:

```
 public static void getPrintJob()
    {
        string printerName = "Some Printer Name";
        string query = string.Format("SELECT * from Win32_Printer WHERE Name LIKE '%{0}'", printerName);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(query);

        while(true)
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();
            var alreadyPrinting = false;
            foreach (ManagementObject printer in coll)
            {
               if (Convert.ToInt32(printer.Properties["PrinterStatus"].Value) == 4 && !alreadyPrinting)
               {
                   Console.Write("Printer is Printing");
                   alreadyPrinting = true;
               }
               else
               {
                    alreadyPrinting = false;
               }
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
```

As RB pointed out in the comments, Thread.Sleep(1000) will pause the loop for 1 second and stop it consuming all the CPU resource.

EDIT:
updated after comments.

Added a bool to track if the printer was already printing. This stops the code writing to the console for as long as the printer is printing. Multiple printers can start and will write to the console. But only once per print job.

Moved the coll variable assignment inside the while loop.

Comment: Note that @1future wrote "*When status of a printer changes*". This solution keeps writing the message until the printer stops printing. Also, I suggest to bind the `while` statement to a "status" variable/property set to `true`, so you can eventually stop the cycle.

Comment: Also, you should include `coll = searcher.Get();` in the loop, because if you don't you will keep checking the old status.Also, you should include `ManagementObjectCollection coll = searcher.Get();`

Comment: Thank you .. your suggest makes a lot of sense to me.. i have done the same thing you have done above .. but what's happening is that when i run the app and th e printer begins to print.. console does not write anything .. but when i run the app whilst the printer is printing , the message is display.. not sure why thiis.

Comment: @1future this is because the query to get the printer's status is only executed when the method is called, and not every second as it should.

Comment: @TommyTopas does searcher.get() not re-run the query? I'll move the new ManagementObjectSearcher(query); inside the loop if not.